# git rm --cached still leaves files somewhere in repo

Tags: git, github

I did a Mercurial -> git conversion using the fast-update utility.  Everything went fine with the conversion.  When I was attempting to push up to github, the push was rejected because some log files in the repo were too large.  I removed them all using:

```
$> git branch
* master
  new_admin_gui
$> git rm -r --cached logs
$> git rm -r --cached out
$> git rm -r --cached tmp
$> git commit -am "Removed files"
$> git checkout new_admin_gui
$> git rm -r --cached logs
$> git rm -r --cached out
$> git rm -r --cached tmp
$> git commit -am "Removed files"
```

When I do a `git push` however, GitHub still rejects the push because
apparently the logs are still sitting in the repo somewhere.  I can't `git rm
-r --cached` any more because it tells me

```
fatal: pathspec 'logs' did not match any files
```

Obviously they are still somewhere in the repo, but I can't figure out where or how to get rid of them.  There are only two branches so I don't think they are hiding out somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git rm --cached` removes the files you're trying to get rid of from *future* commits in your repository, but the log files are still in your repository's *history*. If they're too big to push out to GitHub, you'll need to nuke them from your history, too.

You can do this with the `filter-branch` command, as described in [GitHub's help documentation:](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch logs/ out/ tmp/' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```